# How to list all the objects with a specific date no matter the time in a DateTime Field

Tags: python, django, datetime, orm, date

I Have a model like this

```
foo=models.char
bar=models.dateime
```

In wich several foos arrives in one day in different time. I need to list all the foos in a specific date, no matter the time they arrive.
I can't change the model, so splitting the bar in two fields(one for date and one for time) is out of reach right now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally used the `range` filter and the internal `datetime` timestamps for max/min.  For example:

```
date = datetime.date.today()
YourModel.objects.filter(bar__range=(
                                datetime.datetime.combine(
                                        date,
                                        datetime.time.min
                                    ),
                                datetime.datetime.combine(
                                        date,
                                        datetime.time.max
                                    ),
                            ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a datetime format like so : YYYYMMDD HHmmss 
eg : 20100611 171000 would be the 11th of June 1020, 5:10pm

Assuming a list of models with the following dates: 
20100609 120000
20100611 161204
20100611 121204
20100611 191204

And you want all models for 20100611, in pseudo-code you could do :

```
for (model in models) 
  if (model.datetime >='20100611 000000' or model.datetime<='20100611 235959')
    filtered_foos.add(model.foo)
```

This will effecttively ignore the time part of the date (sorry I don't have a python interpreter the syntax is clearly off but you should get the idea)

Comment: althought your solution is fine, and basically the same as Jack M., Jack' solution is more tied to the Django ORM

Comment: It's fine:) I simply meant to give the general idea of how to do it as I said it is pseudo code.
I don't know the exact syntax of django and couldn't have provided Jack's detailed solution. 
The generic concept can be applied to any language and is useful to know.